# postgres update join doesn't update any records

Tags: postgresql

While executing the following query the records in daily_subscriptions_stats table aren't updated:

```
UPDATE daily_subscriptions_stats dss SET arrivals_count = da.arrivals_count
FROM daily_arrivals da
WHERE da.year = dss.year AND da.month = dss.month AND da.day = dss.day
```

The columns in the daily_subscriptions_stats are the following:

```
consecutive_day, bigint
date, timestamp
arrivals_count, integer
departures_count, integer
year, integer
month, integer
day, integer
```

AND in daily_arrivals the following:

```
year, integer
month, integer
day, integer
arrivals_count, integer
```

Does anyone know why the query doesn't update the records?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the join is actually returning data? What happens if you run that as a select statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
UPDATE daily_subscriptions_stats dss SET arrivals_count =(SELECT da.arrivals_count
FROM daily_arrivals da
WHERE da.year = dss.year AND da.month = dss.month AND da.day = dss.day);
```

[Here is the working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/539ba/1)